# iOS 4.3 doesn't show label on scroll view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiscrollview, uilabel

The Label is on the center of the screen (or below) and iphone 4.3 doesn't show it.
But iphone with iOS 5.0 shows. All made in IB.

UPD: (the code)

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 700)];
        scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Going to need more details to help you. Possibly some code.

Comment: @Popeye I put Label in IB and edited the text. That's it)

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your IB how you are doing it, cause what you have given isn't really anything to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your custom font the same way you would set your font normally in the code doing it like.

```
UIFont *yourFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Medium" size:17.0];
```

You may need to add '-' for the spaces in font Name so it would look like this for the font name.

```
@"Helvetica-Neue-Medium"
@"HelveticaNeue-Medium"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have set label custom font in IB so you need to set custom font in code. 
Please set system font in IB and check in both device.

```
 label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:17.0];
```

Comment: Yes, I used "Helvetica Neue Medium 17.0" font. But how can I change it in the code?

Comment: [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourCustomFontNameHere" size:17.0];

Comment: label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

Comment: @Sheonna8 the _Helvetica Neue Medium_ font is not provided by the iOS under iOS5, you should add it to your project manually for using it on iOS4.